# pendingIntent is fire again again in given radius.

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-alarms, android-pendingintent

i have set multiple approximate alerts in application. i set notifications in this way :

```
private void addProximityAlert(double latitude, double longitude) {

        try{

            LatLonPair latLon;
            for(int i = 0; i < mPositions.size(); i++) {
                latLon = mPositions.get(i);
                Intent intent = new Intent(PROXIMTY_ALERT_INTENT);
                intent.putExtra(ProximityIntentReceiver.EVENT_ID_INTENT_EXTRA, i);
                intent.putExtra(ProximityIntentReceiver.ITEM_NAME,latLon.getItemName());
                intent.putExtra(ProximityIntentReceiver.PLACE_NAME,latLon.getPlaceName());
                PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, i, intent, 0);
                locationManager.addProximityAlert(latLon.getLatitude(), latLon.getLongitude(), radius, expiration,  proximityIntent);// alerts set here.
                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROXIMTY_ALERT_INTENT);
                registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);            

            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.toString();
        }

      }
```

all stored location register for proximity Alert at once .now what happened there when one notification is fire and keep firing again again in given radius. i need to help that how i can remove Alert that has fired once do not give notification again and again when device is still in define radius.

Answer (score 0):

in ProximityIntentReceiver unregister the receiver, so that it won't be called again.

See [unregisterReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unregisterReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver%29)

Comment: if i use unregisterReceiver then my All intent will remove which not fire yet .?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not removing the alerts. The problem is that you are registering the receiver several times. Do it only once.