# BroadCast Receiver ,Pending Intent and Service confusion which to select

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi i have to create an app in which user can mark location so there is an alarm corresponding to that location.i started with BroadCast Receiver i registered with Broadcast receiver every thing was working fine but for a location Pending Intent is firing again and again same problem as described in this article

[here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/mobile-developer-tips-on-location-requests-and-android-proximity-alerts/220).

and there are many queries many people are facing same problem [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462165/pendingintent-is-fire-again-again-in-given-radius)

there is a solution in first article when i register broadcast receiver in activty onCreate  method it worked only when that activity is in focus when i press back then register automatically unregister. i want broadcast receiver to work for all the time. actually there is an alert come up when i click save then a proximity Alert is saved for that location
here is a relevant code for registering a proximity alert related to my app

```
String s=System.currentTimeMillis()+"";


Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT+s);
intent.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
intent.putExtra("latitude", latitude);

       PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), i, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);



locationManager.addProximityAlert(

           latitude, // the latitude of the central point of the alert region

           longitude, // the longitude of the central point of the alert region

           1000, // the radius of the central point of the alert region, in meters

           -1, // time for this proximity alert, in milliseconds, or -1 to indicate no expiration

           proximityIntent // will be used to generate an Intent to fire when entry to or exit from the alert region is detected

      );

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT+s); 

     registerReceiver(new ProximityAlertReceiver(), filter);
```

i am creating an intent with action string contains a constant and a time stamp.then i am registering a Broadcast receiver  with same constant+time_stamp. Alarm is working fine but works only when Activity is in foreground else alarm would not work.can any one please tell How to add proximity alert so that it will fire only once or any alternate solution for accomplishing this task.

Answer (score 0):

because ProximityAlert is firing intent more times and i am showing alarm in an Activty with a note so i used onNewIntent method of Activity so not more than one instance of app generated.